# Is there a way to disable drag&drop in dashing?

Tags: javascript, ruby, dashing

Tried to dig through the JS, but it's above my head. IMO with many dashboards it does not make sense to rearrange things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable dragging by adding an `items` parameter in your `assets/javascripts/application.coffee` file and setting it to 'none' like so:

```
draggable:
    stop: Dashing.showGridsterInstructions
    start: -> Dashing.currentWidgetPositions = Dashing.getWidgetPositions()
    items: "none"
```

The `items` parameter takes a string that matches a CSS selector. It can also take a collection of HTML elements. Only matching elements will be draggable. You can pass any string, as long as it doesn't match any of your widgets. In this case, no elements are matching, which means that drag isn't enabled for anything.