# Dashing: Prevent Movement Of Widgets

Tags: dashboard, dashing

Is there any way to prevent movement / dragging of widgets in a dashing dashboard?

My dashboard works perfectly well but people accidentally move the widgets around. I'd like to fix the dashboard layout to prevent this.

Comment: you can try something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30513122/is-there-a-way-to-disable-dragdrop-in-dashing

Comment: Thank you! That should work a treat!